# Support for Type Properties in g++

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, type-traits

When can we expect support for the [standard type properties](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types#Type_properties_2) in g++? libstdc++ provides support for most of the type properties, with some requiring support from [special GNU extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Type-Traits.html#Type-Traits). However, it would be nice to have complete support for `<type_traits>`, and I am wondering when that will be. I tried inquiring the libstdc++ mailing list, but unfortunately received no response.

If you are wondering which type properties are lacking support, here are some of them:

> Missing is_trivially_copyable, is_assignable, is_copy_assignable,
>   is_move_assignable, is_trivially_constructible,
>   is_trivially_default_constructible, is_trivially_copy_constructible,
>   is_trivially_move_constructible, is_trivially_assignable,
>   is_trivially_default_assignable, is_trivially_copy_assignable,
>   is_trivially_move_assignable, is_trivially_destructible,
>   is_nothrow_assignable, is_nothrow_copy_assignable,
>   is_nothrow_move_assignable, is_nothrow_destructible

Source: search for "Type properties" [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of gcc/libstdc++ are you using?  Which traits are not implemented yet?  Note that some of these will always require compiler support--there is no way to implement some of them solely in a library.

Comment: g++-4.7.1 <3 -- the latest release. I edited the question to include some of the missing properties.

Comment: Wish I knew if anyone was working on it. Trunk's still looks like this:/// is_trivially_constructible (still unimplemented)
  
  /// is_trivially_default_constructible (still unimplemented)

  /// is_trivially_copy_constructible (still unimplemented)

  /// is_trivially_move_constructible (still unimplemented)

  /// is_trivially_assignable (still unimplemented)

  /// is_trivially_copy_assignable (still unimplemented)

  /// is_trivially_move_assignable (still unimplemented)

Comment: _"There is limited support for a few of these type properties in gcc"_ They're part of the standard library, so they're provided by libstdc++, not the compiler front-end, and there's support for most of <type_traits> in libstdc++. The few that are missing were added late in the C++0x process, libstdc++ still provides the older forms such as has_trivial_default_constructor, changed by open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3142.html

Comment: See also http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-08/msg00037.html

Comment: Thanks for the input; I edited my question. It was wrong for me to say that there is limited support for type properties, since most of them are indeed supported. I was thinking about a subset of the operations, including `is_copy_*` and `is_move_*`, of which fewer are implemented.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Do you want to make your comment an answer? Until someone implements the type properties, there isn't much else that can be said.

Comment: IIRC they are supported in gcc 4.8.

Comment: Any progress with this? I am still getting compile errors with `g++-4.8.1`.

Comment: @user1095108 AFAIK all of them are implemented now. Which ones don't work?

Comment: check here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html and you'll see some are still missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're part of the standard library, so they're provided by libstdc++, not the compiler front-end, and there's support for most of  in libstdc++.

The few that are missing were added late in the C++0x process by [N3142](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3142.html) but libstdc++ still provides the older forms such as `has_trivial_default_constructor` instead of `is_trivially_default_constructible`.

As for when, "it depends". See http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-08/msg00037.html and the following replies.

Comment: Following up on this a bit. Does this mean that we will need to wait for GCC 5?  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64195#c1

Comment: Yes, that's right. They're in GCC's subversion trunk now, which will be GCC 5