# Is there a conjunction of type predicates that correspond to std::is_pod<>?

Tags: c++11, type-traits

I try to understand the POD concept in terms of other type predicates.

Is there a complete list of type predicates that would correspond to `std::is_pod<>`?

Here is my current attempt which does not hold (VS2013).

```
struct C { // Does not assert as POD class
    int value;

    C() = default;

    C(int v) : value(v) { // Offends is_pod<>
    }
};

static_assert(std::is_trivial<C>::value, ""); // Assert OK
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<C>::value, ""); // Assert OK
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<C>::value, ""); // Assert OK
static_assert(std::is_pod<C>::value, "");  // Assert fails. Why?
```

Comment: Test passes on clang++3.5 (but `is_trivially_copyable` isn't found o.O)

Comment: Probably a VS2013 bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800418/pod-rules-do-not-respect-explicitly-defaulted-constructor

Comment: @Dyp See [Support for Type Properties in g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919903/support-for-type-properties-in-g). I think you need to use `__has_trivial_copy(C)` instead.

Comment: @dyp One up for pointing out the VS2013 bug that has the corresponding test case to mine.

Answer (score 4):

The combination of `is_trivial` and `is_standard_layout` is equal to `is_pod`, modulo some other restrictions on non-static members that are not captured by one of the type traits in `<type_traits>`.

Relevant quote from [the draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3691.pdf):

**[class]**

> 10 A POD struct is a non-union class that is both a **trivial class**
>   and a **standard-layout class**, and has no non-static data members of
>   type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types).
>   Similarly, a POD union is a union that is both a trivial class and a
>   standard-layout class, and has no non-static data members of type
>   non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types). A POD class is
>   a class that is either a POD struct or a POD union.

Comment: The "and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types)" suggests that there may be types that are trivial and standard-layout, but not POD. I cannot think of any examples, though, and it's not relevant to the question, as the only data member has type `int`.

Comment: @hvd What about a standard-layout class that isn't trivial? E.g. a resource class owning a pointer. (This class should be a valid data member of a standard-layout class, but not of a POD class.)

Comment: @TemplateRex A class with reference members isn't standard-layout.

Comment: @dyp But I cannot see how a class containing a non-trivial class as a data member can itself be trivial.

Comment: @hvd If it's a broken resource class, it uses the trivial default copy ctor etc. ;)

Comment: @dyp But what part of the resource class would be non-trivial, then, but wouldn't render the container class non-trivial? Or, if the resource class is trivial, and standard-layout, and no special members, then what makes it non-POD, so that it serves as an example?

Comment: @TemplateRex It's the NSDMI that makes it non-trivial, not the pointer.

Comment: Hmmm it seems not to be as simple as I thought due to the recursive nature of the *trivially copyable* and *trivial default ctor* requirements.

Comment: Maybe you could use something like `struct X { X(X&) {}; X(X const&) = default; };` It's not trivial, but classes that have it as a member should be, as their copy ctor selects the trivial `X(X const&)`.

Comment: @dyp a class with an in-class initializer is non-trivial (has a non-trivial default constructor), yet it is standard-layout. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f13e43529d16dd55).

Comment: @dyp That renders a container class non-trivial, according to both GCC and clang, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @TemplateRex Yes, that's what I just said in reply to your earlier comment about a pointer. :) But is there something that *is* trivial, *is* standard-layout, but *isn't* POD?

Comment: @hvd I was first finding an example to dyp's question. Now on to your more tricky question!

Comment: @hvd Because it has a non-trivial copy ctor. But if used as a data member, say `struct Y { X x; };`, then `Y` should be trivial again.

Comment: @TemplateRex But a class that uses it as a data member isn't trivial IIRC.

Comment: @dyp Yes, that's what I meant, the container class (`Y` in your example) is non-trivial, according to both GCC and clang.

Comment: @hvd I forgot the default-ctor :)

Comment: Voilà, a class that is trivial, standard-layout, but shouldn't be POD. Unfortunately, clang++3.5 + libstdc++ accept is as POD, which seems to be broken: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/754a60347d0afc9f

Comment: Indeed, there's another [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/796387/class-that-is-trivial-and-standard-layout-results-as-non-pod) posted about a month earlier than the one dyp posted.

Comment: @remyabel changing the default constructor to `=default` in `class D`, makes it OK on clang 3.5 + libstdc++.

Comment: @dyp Ah, nice! I don't know whether it's a bug in just clang, or GCC and clang. GCC says Y is non-trivial and non-POD, clang (testing with 3.3) says Y is trivial and POD. I think it's clear that it shouldn't be POD, but I'm not sure about the triviality. (BTW, it doesn't matter whether you use libstdc++ or libc++, clang gives the same results with both.)

Comment: @dyp you should answer the question with 'no' ;)

Comment: @dyp I now think your example is entirely correct. GCC seems to track copy constructor triviality per type, rather than per constructor, so that can never work when a type has multiple copy constructors, some trivial, some non-trivial. clang checks POD-ness by checking for triviality and standard-layout, and contains a comment that the check for non-POD class data members is redundant, which you've now shown is incorrect.

Comment: @TemplateRex Thank you for a precise answer. Fortunately for me, all the ifs and buts in this thread are not in the scope of my concern. I am impressed by the depth of the discussion.